# Impossible to delete folder Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, directory, windows-7-x64

I have a folder (cygwin) in my Program Files directory that can not be deleted.  I am the administrator, and also the system administrator and still cannot delete the folder.  I have tried deleting it with the command prompt (running it as administrator) and still cannot delete the folder.  Is there any super be-all end-all way to delete this folder?

Comment: Is there a message accompanying the failed delete?

Comment: Yea, it just says "you require the permission of "Macbook\Administrator to make changes to this folder"  but I can change "Macbook\Administrator" to whoever I make the owner of the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do this in cmd:

go to the `cd` where the folder is (example desktop)

```
cd desktop

attrib -s -h -r cygwin

cacls cygwin /e /c /g %username%:f

after that go to the cd were the folder his and try this

cd cygwin

del *.* /s /q

cd..

rd cygwin /s /q
```

I hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether what methods you've already used, but perhaps from an administrator command prompt you could try running "rd /s" on it?  This would remove any subdirectories and files that might be hidden or set as system files that would otherwise prevent a delete.

Comment: I see that elsewhere others have recommended [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) as an option with some success.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the folder was owned by a user that is not on my system. I don't claim to understand how that happened, but here is how I was able to finally remove the files.

First I had broken my cygwin install with previous delete commands, so I actually re-installed enough packages to have the terminal again.  Then launched the terminal with administrator privileges and from cygwin prompt ran:

```
cd /cygdrive/c
chown -R `whoami` cygwin
```

This gave my current windows user the permissions to the folder and I was able to delete.